# How can I decelerate my inertial scroll algorithm when it nears the top or bottom?

Tags: javascript, animation, physics

I have written a small inertial scrolling algorithm for mousewheels in javascript.

It works perfectly for my needs however there is one part missing and I cannot seem to get the desired behaviour.

As the user scrolls to the end of the container, be it the top or the bottom.  I would like to momentum to naturally decelerate to a stop.  Currently it just halts instantly when it hits either edge, whatever speed it is currently going.

Rather than post a load of code here I have created a small jsfiddle to illustrate:

https://jsfiddle.net/o8xLw68L/8/

This is a simplified version of my current code.  If you uncomment line `111` You can kind of see the behaviour I am looking for if you scroll down a little from the top of the `div` and then flick the mousewheel up reasonably quickly.  You will see the momentum slow naturally ot the `0` position.

```
Inertial.prototype.smoothWheel = function(amt) {
     this.targetY += amt;

     //uncomment this line to see the decelleration almost work against the top edge of the container
     //this.targetY = Math.max(0, this.targetY);

     this.vy += (this.targetY - this.oldY) * this.stepAmt;
     this.oldY = this.targetY;
}
```

The problem with this approach is that it only dampens the resulting `this.vy` property when the mousewheel pulses and therefore does not always work correctly since the user may be scrolling from lower down in the container, and at a faster speed, but without any continuing mousewheel pulses. (This is hard to articulate, the jsFiddle should make it clearer)

The solution will likely need to somehow dampen the `this.vy` property as we get sclose to the top or the bottom of the container, so that it  decellerates at a faster pace than the natural `this.friction` property allows.

I am happy for the dampening area to be either hardcoded to be when you reach `300px` of the top/bottom of the content. Or it alternatively, a percentage of the container height would work also.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible to dampen the velocity to the value that is enough just to touch the top or bottom edge only by inertial motion (with friction) independently of mouse wheel speed.

Suppose that in current direction the distance to travel `x` is given. So, it is needed to find the velocity `v0` which is enough to travel that distance with inertial motion with friction.

Current scrolling dynamics (`vy *= friction`) corresponds to laminar fluid flow. It can be written as differential equation:

```
dv = - (1 - friction) * v * dt; // velocity change dv in time interval dt
dv / v = - (1 - friction) * dt;
// integrating lhs and rhs with initial conditions (v = v0 at t = 0)
ln(v/v0) = - (1 - friction) * t;
v = v0 * exp(- (1 - friction) * t);
```

So, the velocity decays exponentially from `v0` to zero with time.

Traveled distance:

```
dx = v * dt = v0 * exp(- (1 - friction) * t) * dt;
// integrating, initial conditions x = 0 at t = 0
x = v0 / (1 - friction) * (1 - exp(- (1 - friction) * t))
```

Thus it is possible to travel the following distance with starting velocity `v0` in infinite time:

```
x = v0 / (1 - friction);
```

Basing on the distance that is left to the edge it is possible to bound the velocity:

```
Inertial.prototype.boundVelocity = function () {
    var dist = 0;

    if (this.dir == 1)
        dist = this.scrollerPos;
    else if (this.dir == -1)
        dist = this.contentHeight - this.scrollerHeight - this.scrollerPos;

    var maxv = dist * (1 - this.friction) + 1;

    if (Math.abs(this.vy) > maxv) {
        console.log('reduce velocity ' + this.vy + ' to ' + (-maxv * this.dir) + ', dist: ' + dist);
        this.vy = -maxv * this.dir;
    }
}
```

There is some small non zero minimal value for `maxv` (`+1`) to make sure the edges are always hit despite of discretization errors. That function is called when the velocity can be increased in `smoothWheel()` and also it is called in `render()` just to avoid numerical error accumulation.

The runnable example: https://jsfiddle.net/c675bkn9/

Comment: What a fantastic answer. Concise and easily understandable.  Thank you.